# Convert a str to path type?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, path

I am trying to interface with some existing code that saves a configuration, and expects a file path that is of type `path.path`.  The code is expecting that the file path is returned from a pygtk browser window (via another function).  I want to call the `save_config` function elsewhere in my code with a file path based on different inputs, constructed from string elements.

When I try to run the code, I am able to construct the file path correctly, but it is a string type, and the save function expects a `path.path` type.

Is there a way to convert a string to a path type?  I've tried searching, but could only find the reverse case (path to string).  I also tried using `os.path.join()`, but that returns a string as well.

Edit: This is python 2.7, if that makes a difference.

Comment: `path.path(config_string)`

Comment: What is `path.path`? Sounds like a class that is defined by the code you are using; it's not a standard type or class. Prior to Python 3.4, there was no standard for paths; functions operating on paths just used the string representation. Python 3.4 introduced the `pathlib` module, which provides proper objects to represent paths.

Comment: When I run `type(file_path)`, I get `<class 'path.path'>` as a response.  There is a `from path import path` line at the top of my file.  I'm assuming this is just `os.path`, but I'm new to this, and the guy who wrote this tool left the company.

Comment: It's not `os.path` which is a module in the standard library, so it must be something else. After the `import`, see what `help(path)` says — there may be something that does what you want.

Answer (score 72):

Since python 3.4:

```
from pathlib import Path
str_path = "my_path"
path = Path(str_path)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib

Answer (score 27):

Maybe that answer worked for python 2.7, if you are on Python 3 I like:

```
import os

p = "my/path/to/file.py"
os.path.normpath(p)
'my\\path\\to\\file.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

If `path.path` represents a type, you can probably create an instance of that type with something like:

```
string_path = "/path/to/some/file"
the_path = path.path(string_path)
save_config(the_path())
```